# Root Gone but still works for many Apps

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, ota-update, root-access

I Have a Verizon Galaxy Nexus which was rooted. I used an [OTA Rootkeeper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.projectvoodoo.otarootkeeper&hl=en) to keep the root after I upgraded to 4.0.4 which worked great, I was able to use root well after the OTA update. But recently the root has stopped working however the apps that I had saved permission before the mysterious removal of root still work. So I can use Sixaxis, Wifi Tether, File Explorer with root permissions, etc. They all work great however any new app I download is unable to get root access. I first noticed it trying to flash a rom.

When I go into SU app says I have a outdated binary and when I try to update it (from 3.0.3) it fails to gain root access.

**Any ideas why I've lost root access and how I can get it back short of going back through the entire root process?**

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "root has stopped working"?  Are there any error messages?

Comment: No error messages. As I said in the post I had root on my phone that worked fine but recently something has changed which has caused it to break i.e. new apps I can install can't gain root access. But apps that previously had root permission still work.

Comment: Looks like problem with su program rather than root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having "root" just means you have a working `su` binary installed (the "su" application is generally just a management front-end for the linux-level binary installed in `/system/bin` or `/system/xbin`).  So, something has gone wrong with the binary, or the way its installed, or its permissions, or its location, or ...

I suspect the apps that still work must have `chown`'d themselves once at setup time?  So they only need `su` to work once, and after that they're good to go.

If you can connect an `adb` shell or run an [Android Terminal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en) (that was just the first play store search hit, I'm not endorsing that specific terminal), type "su" and see if you get a meaningful error.  You can use `adb` to copy a new `su` binary over, or just re-"root" the device.  See the FAQ questions here: http://androidsu.com/superuser/faq/